# in Flash CS6, how can I make a button disappear when clicked?

Tags: flash, button, adobe, action

I am attempting to make a button disappear after the button itself is clicked to reveal the image that is layered underneath it. It can have any effect in order to do this, I just need it to become transparent or to go off of the screen. help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button called "myButton":

```
//listen for mouse clicks
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);

//handle mouse clicks
function mouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //stop listening for clicks
    myButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);
    //make button invisible
    myButton.visible = false;
}
```

This will make button disappear instantly when it is clicked. If you want to apply a fade effect...

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);

function mouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut);
}

function fadeOut(event:Event):void
{
    var a:Number = myButton.alpha-0.05;
    if (a<=0)
    {
        a = 0;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut);
    }
    myButton.alpha = a;
}
```